# Using compressed(ETC1) textures in LibGDX

Tags: opengl, android, textures, libgdx, compression

I use standard android tool for compressing PNG texture and archiving it with gzip:

```
/android-sdks/tools/etc1tool texture.png --encodeNoHeader
gzip texture.pkm
```

Then I try to load it:

```
FileHandle file = ...;
ETC1.ETC1Data data = new ETC1.ETC1Data(file);
ETC1TextureData td = new ETC1TextureData(data, false);
Texture texture = new Texture(td);
```

But I get an `java.nio.BufferOverflowException` inside `ETC1Data (FileHandle pkmFile)` constructor:

```
  in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new GZIPInputStream(pkmFile.read())));
  int fileSize = in.readInt();
  compressedData = BufferUtils.newUnsafeByteBuffer(fileSize);
  int readBytes = 0;
  while ((readBytes = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
      compressedData.put(buffer, 0, readBytes);//Exception occurs here
  }
  compressedData.position(0);
  compressedData.limit(compressedData.capacity());
```

How to fix it? Thanks.

ps if it's important: unarchived pkm file size is 33KB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard tool from Google is not suitable for compression. But [ETC1Compressor](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/extensions/gdx-tools/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tools/etc1/ETC1Compressor.java) works fine.